# chrome devtools - memory chart in performance tab do not display any info

Tags: performance, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to learn how to use the performance tab from chrome devtools and I cannot seem to understand why the memory chart that is supposed to show me some info regarding JS Heap, Nodes, etc., is not displaying any info after a recording.

This is the specific feature I am referring to:

- https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/performance/reference#memory

This is the simple tutorial that I am following:

- https://www.debugbear.com/blog/debugging-javascript-memory-leaks

Every time I do a recording (either by loading the page or just clicking the button as shown in the tutorial) I get an empty memory chart.

I am on latest chrome version (macOS): Version 121.0.6167.85 (Official Build) (arm64)

What I am missing here?

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem on macOS Sonoma 14.2.1, Chrome 121.0.6167.139 (arm64). MS Edge (121.0.2277.83) has the same issue. Notably, the DevTools bundled with VS Code 1.85.2 (which is based on Chromium 114.0.5735.289) does not have this issue.
Also, someone has reported this bug in Chromium's tracker: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1521359

Comment: Yeah, it seems like a chromium bug indeed. Thanks a lot for the related link!